# Determine if we checked out a branch or a tag with git

Tags: git

In a script, I would like to determine if a tag or a branch was checked out.

For now, I have:

```
git describe --tags
```

It will show the tag name, but if we are on a branch, it will raise an error (with return status != `0`):

```
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
```

Can I rely on this behavior or is there a better/more official way to do so?

Are there some cases that are not caught by this method that I should know?

Comment: I am on a branch and `git describe --tags` doesn't throw any error. It just shows the first reachable tag from where you are

Comment: @iberbeu Yes I noticed that, `git describe --tags` is not good for this, see my own answer ^^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `git symbolic-ref HEAD` to check if you are on a branch and get its name:

```
> git checkout master
[....]
> git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/master
> echo $?
0
```

If you have checked out a tag you will get an error:

```
> git checkout some_tag
[....]
> git symbolic-ref HEAD
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
> echo $?
128
```

Answer (score 1):

(edit) better than what I had earlier:

```
if read what where huh; test "$what" = ref:
then echo On branch ${where#refs/heads/}
else echo "not on any branch; last checkout was:"
     git reflog|sed '/checkout:/!d;q'
fi < "`git rev-parse --git-dir`"/HEAD
```

will tell you where your last checkout came from.

```
git log HEAD^! --oneline --decorate
```

will tell you all the symbolic names for your current commit.

Answer (score 0):

**git status** (or **git branch**) to know on which branch you are. 
Note: you're always on a branch: the default branch is *master*.

Use **git tag** to know the list of tags on the current branch.

Comment: When I am on a tag, `git branch` will show that I'm on `* (no-branch)` so I guess I'm not always on a branch? Also `git tag` is not very helpful to know on *which* tag I am (i.e. which tag I checked out).

Comment: (I replied posting another answer)

Answer (score 0):

Well after some testing around, it turns out `git describe --tags` wasn't very reliable (in one case I had checked out a branch it did return something).

I ended up using:

```
git branch | grep '^*'
```

This will return the selected branch. In case I checked out a tag, this will return:

```
* (no branch)
```

In my script I parse the string to check if it contains `(no branch)`.

Comment: and what if you are on a branch and on a tag at a time? In that case git tells you that you are not on a branch, while you actually are